# How do I add an onClick event to a link generated on PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I am trying to add an onclick event on a link in a PHP file.

```
$body2 .= '<td class="sampling-list-td download-link">' . '<a ' . 'class="sampling-list-download" ' . 'href="#" ' . 'data-id="' . $assetId . '" ' . 'data-type="' . $assetType . '" ' . 'data-event="LogFileElaboration" ' . 'data-file="' . $fileName . '" ' . 'data-enterprise="' . $provisionedBuId . '"' . '>'
                . '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" style="color: rgb(109, 110, 113); zoom: 1.3;"></i>'
                    . '</a>' . '</td>';
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
 $body2 .= '<td class="sampling-list-download" ' . 'onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'download', eventAction: 'click', eventLabel: 'Files Download'});" ' . 'href="#" ' . 'data-id="' . $assetId . '" ' . 'data-type="' . $assetType . '" ' . 'data-event="LogFileElaboration" ' . 'data-file="' . $fileName . '" ' . 'data-enterprise="' . $provisionedBuId . '"' . '>'
                . '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" style="color: rgb(109, 110, 113); zoom: 1.3;"></i>'
                    . '</a>' . '</td>';
```

But I am getting the following errors:

**ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'send' (T_STRING)**

I don't know what i'm doing wrong? I'm trying to add the event tracking code for google analytics T_T

Comment: Did you read the error message? It clearly says that you have a syntax error at send, meaning: `. 'onClick="ga('send', 'event'`. You open code with `'` and then use the same quotations in JS files. You probably want to escape those with `\'`

Comment: I would also recommend getting an editor/IDE which shows errors in your code as you type.

Answer (score 3):

the quote in `'send'` ends the string you started right before onClick. When the string is terminated it will interpret as PHP again and `send` is not a valid keyword here.

To prevent this you can escape the `'` like this: `'onClick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', { e...`

Comment: Hello, thank you @JensV . Is there a way I could use the $fileName as the eventLabel ?

Comment: @JCColp well yes. Just concat it into the eventLabel like so: `eventLabel: \''.$fileName.'\'`

Answer (score 1):

Its a Quote problem .change like this add`\` before `'` in onclick.Otherwise each time `'` .is break the string and after the text are execute like php statement or variable .If the php `send` is invalid one so you got error

```
 $body2 .= '<td class="sampling-list-download" ' . 'onClick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', { eventCategory: \'download\', eventAction: \'click\', eventLabel: \'Files Download\'});" ' . 'href="#" ' . 'data-id="' . $assetId . '" ' . 'data-type="' . $assetType . '" ' . 'data-event="LogFileElaboration" ' . 'data-file="' . $fileName . '" ' . 'data-enterprise="' . $provisionedBuId . '"' . '>'
                . '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" style="color: rgb(109, 110, 113); zoom: 1.3;"></i>'
                    . '</a>' . '</td>';
```

Comment: thank you! this worked perfectly.  Is there a way I could use the $fileName as the eventLabel ?